# How to complete a graph assigning 0 as weight attribute of new edges

Tags: r, igraph

Please consider the following graph

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 2/100)
E(g)$weight <- sample(1:10, ecount(g), replace=TRUE)
```

I am interested in "completing" the graph by adding all missing edges (as a result each pair of vertices will be connected by an edge) but making sure the new edges are assign E(g)$weight = 0.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
olde = E(g)                       # saving edges
g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE             # adding all possible edges
E(g)$weight <- 0                  # all weights is 0 
E(g)[olde]$weight <- olde$weight  # old weights is equal to old weights  
g <- simplify(g)                  # removing loops
```

According to the comments, I would like to suggest more robust answer that is based on the extra attribute of edges,
please see below and give comments.

```
ids = E(g)                        # saving old ids
E(g)$oldids = ids                 # assigning to specific edge as extra attribute
olde = E(g)                       # saving edges

g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE             # adding all possible edges
E(g)$weight <- 0                  # all weights is 0 

# Now it is more robust, because it matches oldids with the ids of old graph
E(g)[match(ids, oldids)]$weight <- olde$weight[ids]  # old weights is equal to old weights
```

Comment: This only works because the internal ids of the initial edges do not change. This is not guaranteed to be the case in future igraph versions. In general, you cannot use an `E(g)` with another graph. (After adding the new edges, `g` is another graph.)

Comment: @GaborCsardi Do you want to suggest an a more robust alternative?

Comment: Create a full graph first, set all edge weights to zero, then set each edges to non-zero weights according to a Bernoulli trial.

Comment: I would like to disagree (at least in small part). 
Based on the 'igraph' documentation (see ?add.edges), the operation 
"g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE" 
does not affect edges that are already present in the graph,
therefore you can expect that the internal ids of the initial edges do not change.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I am working on a real graph. Should I create a new full graph with same `vcount` and then copy to the new graph all the attributes of the real graph? Then you seem to say I CAN'T complete an existing graph.

Comment: @Vyga: Hmmm, you are right, actually. I forgot that.

Comment: @CptNemo: I gave you a way to solve the problem you were asking about. How should I guess that you are actually having a different problem?

Comment: Btw. if you have a complete graph, it is better to use a simple adjacency matrix. Igraph is both slower and more difficult to use in this case.

Comment: @Vyga I have being testing your code on a relatively small graph and it works. Still for a very large graph I hit the limits of the OS: at the line `g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE` is `killed` by the OS without further explanations (probably memory limit).

Comment: @CptNemo: yes, indeed, it is most likely to be a memory limit.