# Add 1 to all values of a large adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I want to build a full graph out of an existing graph of a real network. The nodes have an attribute `weight`. The full graph should keep the same attributes of existing edges and set the `weight` of the new edges to 0.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619957/1707938) works for small graphs (on my 32gb RAM instance up to approximately 10K nodes) but with a graph with 80K+ nodes and 80M edges my script is `killed` by the OS at the line `g[V(g), V(g)] <- TRUE`.

I then need to know whether another solution is possible. In the code below I convert the graph to its adjacency matrix with `get.adjacency()`, add 1 to all values, convert it back to a full graph with `graph.adjacency()`, subtract 1 from all `weight`s, and then pass all the nodes attributes from the original graph to the new full graph.

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(5, 1/5)
V(g)$size <- sample(1:10, vcount(g), replace=TRUE)
V(g)$time <- sample(1:10000, vcount(g), replace=TRUE)
E(g)$weight <- sample(1:10, ecount(g), replace=TRUE)

adj <- get.adjacency(g, attr="weight", sparse=TRUE)
adj <- adj + 1
g2 <- graph.adjacency(adj, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE, weighted=TRUE)
E(g2)$weight <- E(g2)$weight - 1

V(g2)$size <- V(g)$size 
V(g2)$time <- V(g)$time

g.full <- graph.full(5)
vcount(g.full) == vcount(g2)
# [1] TRUE
V(g2)$size == V(g)$size
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
V(g2)$time == V(g)$time
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

The trick works, but only on small graph. The bottle neck is at `adj <- adj + 1` which for a large graph gives

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error does not have much to do with igraph. After `get.adjacency` you have a sparse graph and

```
adj <- adj + 1
```

essentially converts it to a dense matrix. To have a dense matrix with 80,000 rows/columns you need 80,000 * 80,000 * 8 bytes of memory, which is about 48GB. Actually, even if you have that much memory, most probably it will not work, because R will want to copy the matrix at least once, so you need twice of this.

And then if you want to create an igraph graph from it, you'll need much more memory than this ~100GB, because igraph was designed for sparse graphs, and it is not very efficient with memory if the graph is dense. It needs (2*n+4*m)*8 bytes of memory, where n is the number of vertices and m is the number of edges. You will need another m*8 bytes of memory for the weights, and n*4 bytes for the other (integer) attributes, per attribute.

So I would suggest to use some graph analysis software that stores the data on the disk, or consider another data representation, e.g. **not** storing the edges that have zero weight.

Comment: This is a problem I am trying to solve since few weeks. What I want is a regression model: as response the edge `weight` and as predictors the attributes of the corresponding pair of nodes. For my graph `g` what I aim to get then is a matrix with `nrow==ecount(graph.full(vcount(g)))` and as columns `weight` plus two columns, one for each attribute of the corresponding pair of nodes... I don't need to build a full graph, but I am not sure how should I proceed to get my matrix to run the regression...

Comment: This is not related to the original question but rather a comment on what you want to do. If your original graph is sparse, then most of the weights that your regression model will try to predict will be zeros. There is a very high chance that a naive regression model will not "learn" how to reproduce the nonzero values at all. I would rather select `ecount(g)` random vertex pairs for which there is no edge between them and add zero weights only for those - this makes the training set of your regression model more balanced.

Comment: @CptNemo: a matrix with `nrow==ecount(graph.full(vcount(g)))` is equivalent to a full graph. You just reshaped your `n x n` matrices to be `n*n x 3`. You'll need about the same amount of memory for this. (In fact, more, because you store integer values as real numbers.)

Comment: OK, that seems like a no go.